# Swiftui load data from multiple Firestore call

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am trying to fetch data from firestore. First call fetching data from a firestore collection where each document contains two fields, name and image name. This is working fine. With the Second call using firebase storage am fetching the image using the image name from the first call. Since am a beginner in swiftui struggling a bit to set the image from firebase storage. Below is my code, kindly shed some light.

```
struct StoreCategory : Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id : String?
    var image : String?
    var name : String?
}

class HomeViewModel : ObservableObject {
  @Published var storeCategoryLst : [StoreCategory] = []
  @Published var imageURL : [URL] = []

   init() {
    self.fetchStoreCategory()
}

    func fetchStoreCategory()  {
        firestore.collection(Constants.COL_STORE_CATEGORY).addSnapshotListener { snapShot, error in
            guard let documents = snapShot?.documents else{
                print("No Documents found")
                return
            }
                self.storeCategoryLst = documents.compactMap({ (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> StoreCategory? in
                return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as:StoreCategory.self )
            })
            
            self.storeCategoryLst.map { item in
                self.LoadCategoryImages(name: item.name ?? "")
            }

            print(self.storeCategoryLst.count)

        }
    }

    func LoadCategoryImages(name : String) {
        let storageRef = storageRef.reference().child("common/\(name.lowercased()).png")
        storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Hey \(name)")
                print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            var imgURL = URL(string: url!.absoluteString)
            self.imageURL.append(imgURL!)
            print(self.imageURL.count)
            imgURL = url
        }
    }

}




struct CategoryView : View {
    @StateObject var homeViewModel : HomeViewModel = HomeViewModel()
    @State var url = ""
    var columns = Array(repeating:GridItem(.flexible(minimum : 100, maximum : 200)) , count: 3)
    var body: some View {
            
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing:8){
                
                ForEach(homeViewModel.storeCategoryLst){   item in
                    
                    ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: . trailing, vertical: .top)){
                        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 15){
                        
                            AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: "")).resizable().frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                            Text(item.name ?? "").font(.caption).multilineTextAlignment(.center)//.frame(height : 30)
                            
                        }.padding()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius:5, x:-5, y:5)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            print(item.name)
                        }
                    
                    }
                    
                }
            }.padding(.horizontal)
            
            
        
    }
}
```

How to load the image in a right way? Thanks a ton.

Comment: You need to use the debugger and your print statements to find out where it's failing. For example, you're using `try?` to decode your model. Are you sure it's working? Use `do/try/catch` and print the error. Does it reach `print(self.storeCategoryLst.count)`? Does the program get to `print("Hey \(name)")`? The compiler is probably warning you about an unused return from `self.storeCategoryLst.map` -- use `forEach` instead.

Comment: Everything is working fine, the only issue is am loading LazyVgrid data from categorylist. But my image URL is in imageURL array. How I can display the image from a separate array?

Comment: Store your image URLs in a dictionary where the key is the category ID and the value is the URL of the image.

Comment: That sounds good. I ll try and let you know soon. while loading the category list in LazyVGrid there was some delay in fetching image links from firebase storage and that leads to a crash.  Because I received only a category list and not an image list. Any idea on this?

Comment: You'd have to say what the error was when it crashed

Comment: As I said earlier it was crashing because the array doesn't have data. View loading before the data comes from firestore. So obviously array out of index error.

Comment: I don't see any place in your current code where you're explicitly loading by index. But, it's not a [mre], so I can't test it.